# Java 8 Map & Stream - Sorting by value desc and group

Tags: sorting, group-by, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I need to sort by descending order the response data by count sum after they grouped up in Java 8.

I have a view table query result like:

| count(bigint) | category(varchar) | myEnum(int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 0 |
| 35 | B | 0 |
| 30 | A | 1 |
| 25 | C | 1 |

I have a projection interface for the view table for customizing the result of JPA Queries.

```java
public interface MyView {

    Long getCount();

    String getCategory();

    MyEnum getMyEnum();
}
```

And this one is my DTO for the response:

```java
public class MyResponse {

    private List<Long> count = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<List<MyEnum>> myEnums = new ArrayList<>();

    // ctors, getters and setters
}
```

I need to group the data by category and sum the total counts, then collect the Enum types in a list for each category. According to this, the count of category A should be 40 and has 0,1 enum types.
So, client-side needs to get the result like following after the get request:

```json
{
  "count": [
    40,
    35,
    25
  ],
  "categories": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "myEnums": [
    [
      "ENUM_A",
      "ENUM_B"
    ],
    [
      "ENUM_A",
    ],
    [
      "ENUM_B",
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is the related function in my service:

```java
    public MyResponse foo() {
        // This list have the list of MyView.
        List<MyView> myList = myRepository.getCountView());

        Map<String, List<MyView>> myMap = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyView::getCategory));

        MyResponse response = new MyResponse();

        myMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    response.getCategories().add(key);
                    response.getCount().add(value.stream().mapToLong(MyView::getCount).sum());
                    response.getMyEnums().add(value.stream().flatMap(v -> Stream.of(v.getMyEnum())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
        );

        return response;
    }
```

Alright, I have completed grouping by category and summing the counts but couldn't be able to sort them. The result is true but I need to order the data by total count by descending.
I would be appreciate to you for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Write a `Function<List<MyView>, MyResponse> mapView` that creates a response for a single view list, and a `BinaryOperator<MyResponse> merge` that adds two responses. You can then use those to reduce the original grouping lists: `myList.stream().collect(groupingBy(MyView::getCategory, reducing(MyResponse::new, mapView, merge))`.

Comment: Instead of `.flatMap(v -> Stream.of(v.getMyEnum()))` you can use `.map(v -> v.getMyEnum())` or `.map(MyView::getMyEnum)`. Then, replace `myMap.forEach((key, value) -> …` with something like `myMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(e -> e.getValue().getCount())).forEach(e -> …` which unfortunately means you have to extract `e.getKey()` any `e.getValue()` in the consumer manually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I solved the case, according to @Most Needed Rabbit 's answer. In addition, I applied `.map(v -> v.getMyEnum()) or .map(MyView::getMyEnum)` instead `.flatMap(v -> Stream.of(v.getMyEnum()))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` each entry in the map to a `CategorySummary`, then reduce to a `MyResponse`:

```
List<MyView> myList = Arrays.asList(
        new MyView(30, "B", MyEnum.ENUM_B),
        new MyView(10, "A", MyEnum.ENUM_A),
        new MyView(35, "B", MyEnum.ENUM_A),
        new MyView(25, "C", MyEnum.ENUM_B)
);

Map<String, List<MyView>> myMap = myList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyView::getCategory, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));

MyResponse myResponse = myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new CategorySummary(
                e.getValue().stream().mapToLong(MyView::getCount).sum(),
                e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().stream().flatMap(v -> Stream.of(v.getMyEnum())).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CategorySummary::getCount).reversed())
        .reduce(new MyResponse(),
                (r, category) -> {
                    r.addCategory(category);
                    return r;
                }, (myResponse1, myResponse2) -> { // the combiner won't be invoked because it's sequential stream.
                    myResponse1.getMyEnums().addAll(myResponse2.getMyEnums());
                    myResponse1.getCount().addAll(myResponse2.getCount());
                    myResponse1.getCategories().addAll(myResponse2.getCategories());
                    return myResponse1;
                });

System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myResponse));
```

Output:

```
{
    "count": [65, 25, 10],
    "categories": ["B", "C", "A"],
    "myEnums": [
        ["ENUM_B", "ENUM_A"],
        ["ENUM_B"],
        ["ENUM_A"]
    ]
}
```

---

`CategorySummary`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class CategorySummary {
    private long count;
    private String name;
    private List<MyEnum> myEnums;
}
```

I also had to add an additional method in `MyResponse` class:

```
public void addCategory(CategorySummary categorySummary){
    this.count.add(categorySummary.getCount());
    this.categories.add(categorySummary.getName());
    this.myEnums.add(categorySummary.getMyEnums());
}
```

Comment: Hey @Most Needed Rabbit, thanks for the answer. This solution totally fit. Just worrying about the cost for backend. Do you think that is the best practice or sorting on client-side is better?

Comment: @hayriaral Performance-wise, I think it's better to do it BE because Java is faster. I think there's another thing to consider and it depends on the interface.  As the client-side. would you expect to get the data sorted or is it something that is done just to present the user the information in a specific way that might be changed in the future? If the UI changes, it shouldn't affect the data that is being sent from the BE.

Comment: The data which being sent already serves for other cases, and sorting is not a issue. Just in this case, I need to sort the data and thanks to your solution it solved.